# Cannot set value to object property in Typescipt. Cannot set property 'ismain' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

bellow the class i initialize an object of type Photo, which photo is an interface with some attributes. And then i'm trying to use array filter to filter photos.

The filter return a copy of the photos array but i specify which photo do i want so i will have an array with 1 index inside. And then, i try to set a property inside the object to false, and the "Cannot set property 'ismain' of undefined in angular" occurs. Any ideas why?

Here is my code.

```
setMainPhoto(photo: Photo) {
this.userService
  .setMainPhoto(this.authService.decodedToken.nameid, photo.id)
  .subscribe(
    () => {
      // We use the array filter method to filter the photos apart from the main photo
      // Filter returns a copy of the photos array. Filters out anything that it doesn`t match in the p
      this.currentMain = this.photos.filter(p => p.ismain === true)[0];

      this.currentMain.ismain = false;
      photo.ismain = true;
      this.alertify.success('Successfully set to profile picture');
    },
    error => {
      this.alertify.error('Photo could not be set as profile picture');
    }
  );
}
```

In the above method the error occurs.
And below is my Photo interface.

```
   export interface Photo {

  id: number;
  url: string;
  dateadded: Date;
  ismain: boolean;
  description: string;
}
```

ERROR
[image]

**UPDATE**

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

[image]

The response from the server needs to match with the object attributes. So i had to change the property interface to match the JSON object coming back from the server.

Comment: `this.currentMain = this.photos.filter(p => p.ismain === true)[0]` - are you sure you have any elements in that filtered array afterwards? It's possible `this.currentMain` is `undefined` after this line.

Comment: Which statement is at line 115 of photo-editor.ts ???

Comment: @VLAZ now it is coming. The JSON object from the server it didn`t match the interface parameter

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
setMainPhoto(photo: Photo) {
this.userService
  .setMainPhoto(this.authService.decodedToken.nameid, photo.id)
  .subscribe(
    () => {
      // We use the array filter method to filter the photos apart from the main photo
      // Filter returns a copy of the photos array. Filters out anything that it doesn`t match in the p
      this.currentMain = this.photos.filter(p => p.ismain === true)[0];
      if (this.currentMain) {
          this.currentMain.ismain = false;
          photo.ismain = true;
      this.alertify.success('Successfully set to profile picture'); }
    },
    error => {
      this.alertify.error('Photo could not be set as profile picture');
    }
  );
}
```

If this works, then the filter does not return anything.

Comment: Hi Thanasi - It is comming as undefined... Although in the list of photos i have 4 records, which one of them is ismain = true, how is this possible not to pick that record from the photos list?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, I've had this come up before too. Typescript is quite strict with capitalization and if you don't match the json object exactly, it won't work, create a new property, etc.

I've found it helpful to take a look at the json return before building my typescript model, to make sure I'm matching the object being sent.

Comment: Agree..its better this way